# angularjs sincrono

Tags: angularjs

Tengo el siguiente controlador.js :

```
var result = [];
var d = ["MS_SNA_CONTROL_TAB","MS_SNA_EXT_LOSS_TAB"];

for(var i = 0; i < d.length; i++){ 
  var filter = {};
  filter.name = d[i];

  EOGService.query(queryP).then(
    function(a) {
            filter.results = a;
            console.log("añade : " + d[i])
            results.push(filter);
        }
  ); 

  console.log("ha terminado: " + results);
}
```

Mi problema es  que  el orden de la consola es :

```
ha terminado: undefined
añade MS_SNA_CONTROL_TAB
añade MS_SNA_EXT_LOSS_TAB
```

Y necesito que sea

```
añade MS_SNA_CONTROL_TAB
añade MS_SNA_EXT_LOSS_TAB
ha terminado: object
```

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad de la forma en que estas creando las promesas nunca lograrás controlar cuando finalizen. Para esto debes convertir tu arreglo de valores en un arreglo de promesas y usar `$q.all` para controlar cuando todas han terminado.

Algo como esto

```
var promises = [];
var result;
var d = ["MS_SNA_CONTROL_TAB","MS_SNA_EXT_LOSS_TAB"];

for(var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) { 
    var promise = EOGService.query(queryP);
    promises.push(promise);
}

$q.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    results.forEach(function(a, index) {
        var filter = {};
        filter.name = d[index];
        filter.results = a;
        console.log("añade : " + d[index]);
        results.push(filter);
    });

    console.log("ha terminado: " + results);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en la forma como concibes el funcionamiento de AngularJS (Angular 1), respecto al servicio EOGService que esta usando que es asincronico, en este caso la funcion realmente termina en donde hace el push, y suponiendo que esa sea una funcion haria falta una promesa o un callback para devolver el resultado algo asi

```
function funcAsincronica(callback){
      var result = [];
      var d = ["MS_SNA_CONTROL_TAB","MS_SNA_EXT_LOSS_TAB"];
      for(var i = 0; i < d.length; i++){ 
      var filter = {};
      filter.name = d[i];
      EOGService.query(queryP).then(
      function(a) {
              filter.results = a;
              console.log("añade : " + d[i])
              results.push(filter);
               if(result.length == d.length){
                  callback(result);
               }
       }); 
 }

  funcAsincronica(function(result){
         console.log("ha terminado: " + results);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Asi ya debería hacer lo que quieres sin necesidad de hacerlo sincrono

```html
var result = [];
var d = ["MS_SNA_CONTROL_TAB","MS_SNA_EXT_LOSS_TAB"];

for(var i = 0; i < d.length; i++){ 
  var filter = {};
  filter.name = d[i];

  EOGService.query(queryP).then(
    function(a) {
            filter.results = a;
            console.log("añade : " + d[i])
            results.push(filter);
 console.log("ha terminado: " + results);
        }
  ); 

 
}
```

Comment: Lo que indicas tendria como resultado :

    añade MS_SNA_CONTROL_TAB
    ha terminado: object
    añade MS_SNA_EXT_LOSS_TAB
    ha terminado: object